Dell Precision 3581 doesn't "see" monitor when the output on the monitor is switched
I recently replaced old laptop with the new one (Dell Precision 3581). I also have the monitor ViewSonic VP2780-4K, which is connected via HDMI cable. I also use this monitor with a desktop connected via DP - and switch between outputs on the monitor's menu.
For some reason new laptop "loses" HDMI connection when I switch the monitor to DP - it wasn't an issue on previous laptop.
The laptop always has closed lid and is setup not to sleep while external monitor is connected - by "lose" I mean that laptop doesn't "see" the external monitor anymore after I switch outputs - and goes to sleep. I use Fedora 40 KDE Plasma. Previous laptop had the exactly same setup.
How can I debug this problem and where to start?
My suggested list of culprits:

cable (hasn't changed)
monitor (hasn't changed)
laptop's hardware (+BIOS stuff)
linux kernel drivers (hasn't changed?)
user-space software (hasn't changed?)


The hdmi port is probably using a newer version and uninstalls the monitor everytime its turned off. No way you can prevent that I think. Maybe using an older HDMI cable.
